# Keras ROC different from Scikit ROC?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, nlp, roc

From the code below, it looks like evaluating the roc with keras and with scikit actually makes a difference. Does anybody know an explanation?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout
from keras import Sequential
import keras
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

# training data: X_train, y_train
# validation data: X_valid, y_valid

# Define the custom callback we will be using to evaluate roc with scikit
class MyCustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_epoch_end(self,epoch, logs=None):
        y_pred = model.predict(X_valid)
        print("roc evaluated with scikit = ",roc_auc_score(y_valid, y_pred))
        return

# Define the model.

def model(): 

    METRICS = [ 
          tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
          tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
    ]

    optimizer="adam"
    dropout=0.1
    init='uniform'
    nbr_features= vocab_size-1 #2500
    dense_nparams=256

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(dense_nparams, activation='relu', input_shape=(nbr_features,), kernel_initializer=init,  kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer,metrics = METRICS)
    return model

# instantiate the model
model = model()

# fit the model
history = model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, batch_size = 8, epochs = 8, verbose=1,validation_data = (X_valid,y_valid), callbacks=[MyCustomCallback()], shuffle=True, validation_freq=1, max_queue_size=10, workers=4, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

Output:

```
Train on 4000 samples, validate on 1000 samples
Epoch 1/8
4000/4000 [==============================] - 15s 4ms/step - loss: 0.7950 - accuracy: 0.7149 - auc: 0.7213 - val_loss: 0.7551 - val_accuracy: 0.7608 - val_auc: 0.7770
roc evaluated with scikit =  0.78766515781747
Epoch 2/8
4000/4000 [==============================] - 15s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0771 - accuracy: 0.8235 - auc: 0.8571 - val_loss: 1.0803 - val_accuracy: 0.8574 - val_auc: 0.8954
roc evaluated with scikit =  0.7795984218252997
Epoch 3/8
4000/4000 [==============================] - 14s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0085 - accuracy: 0.8762 - auc: 0.9162 - val_loss: 1.2084 - val_accuracy: 0.8894 - val_auc: 0.9284
roc evaluated with scikit =  0.7705172905961992
Epoch 4/8
4000/4000 [==============================] - 14s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0025 - accuracy: 0.8982 - auc: 0.9361 - val_loss: 1.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.9054 - val_auc: 0.9424
roc evaluated with scikit =  0.7808804338960933
Epoch 5/8
4000/4000 [==============================] - 14s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0020 - accuracy: 0.9107 - auc: 0.9469 - val_loss: 1.1887 - val_accuracy: 0.9150 - val_auc: 0.9501
roc evaluated with scikit =  0.7811174659489438
Epoch 6/8
4000/4000 [==============================] - 14s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0018 - accuracy: 0.9184 - auc: 0.9529 - val_loss: 1.2036 - val_accuracy: 0.9213 - val_auc: 0.9548
roc evaluated with scikit =  0.7822898825544409
Epoch 7/8
4000/4000 [==============================] - 14s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0017 - accuracy: 0.9238 - auc: 0.9566 - val_loss: 1.2231 - val_accuracy: 0.9258 - val_auc: 0.9579
roc evaluated with scikit =  0.7817036742516923
Epoch 8/8
4000/4000 [==============================] - 14s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0016 - accuracy: 0.9278 - auc: 0.9592 - val_loss: 1.2426 - val_accuracy: 0.9293 - val_auc: 0.9600
roc evaluated with scikit =  0.7817419052279585
```

As you may see, from epoch 2 onwards keras' and scikit's validation ROCs begin diverging. The same happens if I fit the model and then use keras' `model.evaluate(X_valid, y_valid)`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: testing the model on a separate test set, I get roc =0.76 so scikit seems to give the correct answer ( btw X_train has 4000 entries, X_valid has 1000 and test has 15000, quite an unconventional splitting but it is forced by external factors).
Also, suggestions on how to improve performance are equally appreciated.

EDIT2: To answer the reply by @arpitrathi, i modified the callbak but unfortunately without success:

```
class MyCustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def on_epoch_end(self,epoch, logs=None):
        y_pred = model.predict_proba(X_valid)
        print("roc evaluated with scikit = ",roc_auc_score(y_valid, y_pred))
        return

model = model()

history = model.fit(x=X_trainl, y=y_train, batch_size = 8, epochs = 3, verbose=1,validation_data = (X_valid,y_valid), callbacks=[MyCustomCallback()], shuffle=True, validation_freq=1, max_queue_size=10, workers=4, use_multiprocessing=True)


Train on 4000 samples, validate on 1000 samples
Epoch 1/3
4000/4000 [==============================] - 20s 5ms/step - loss: 0.8266 - accuracy: 0.7261 - auc: 0.7409 - val_loss: 0.7547 - val_accuracy: 0.7627 - val_auc: 0.7881
roc evaluated with scikit =  0.7921764130168828
Epoch 2/3
4000/4000 [==============================] - 15s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0482 - accuracy: 0.8270 - auc: 0.8657 - val_loss: 1.0831 - val_accuracy: 0.8620 - val_auc: 0.9054
roc evaluated with scikit =  0.78525915504445
Epoch 3/3
4000/4000 [==============================] - 15s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0092 - accuracy: 0.8794 - auc: 0.9224 - val_loss: 1.2226 - val_accuracy: 0.8928 - val_auc: 0.9340
roc evaluated with scikit =  0.7705555215724655
```

Also, if I plot training and validation accuracy, i see that they both rapidly converge to 1. Is it strange?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the arguments that you passed to the `sklearn` function for `roc_auc_score()` calculation. You should use `model.predict_proba()` instead of `model.predict()`.

```
def on_epoch_end(self,epoch, logs=None):
        y_pred = model.predict_proba(X_valid)
        print("roc evaluated with scikit = ",roc_auc_score(y_valid, y_pred))
        return
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @arpitrathi !!. I replied in the EDIT2 of the question.

Comment: Then I suspect it might be due to the set of threshold values that are used in sklearn and keras when discretizing the roc curve. The thresholds in sklearn are determined optimally according to the `y_score` values (you can check them using `fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_scores)`) while keras uses linearly spaced set of thresholds for calculating the AUC scores. Try increasing the `num_thresholds` parameter in `tf.keras.metrics.AUC()` to an arbitrarily large value and see if the scores converge.

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn and keras use different default parameters when computing AUC. Increasing the number of thresholds keras uses to compute AUC (i.e., increasing `num_thresholds`) can help the keras AUC better match the sklearn AUC.